# PyQt4. Ошибка при заполнении таблицы данными

Tags: python, pyqt4

PyQt4, Python3, таблица размером х*у

```
self.model = QtGui.QStandartItemModel(x,y)
```

в первой функции были заполнены первый и второй столбцы таблицы, причем заполнены в цикле и никаких ошибок нет

```
def function1(self):
    file = open ("./" + self.weapon.currentText(), "r")
    q = file.readlines()
    self.model.setRowCount(len(q)) #добавляет в таблицу строки соответственно длине файла
    file.close()
    q2 = []
    x = 0

    for item in q:
        q2.append(item.split("_"))  

    for item in q2:
        i = QtGui.QStandardItem(item[2])
        k = QtGui.QStandardItem(item[1])
        if len(item) > 3:
            l = QtGui.QStandardItem(item[3].replace("(", ""))
            self.model.setItem(x, 1, l)
        else:
            self.model.setItem(x, 1, k)
        self.model.setItem(x, 0, i)            
        x += 1

def function2(self):
    i = QtGui.QStandardItem("12")
    for item in range(0, self.model.rowCount()): 
        #self.model.takeItem(item, 2)
        self.model.setItem(item, 2, i)
```

во второй функции, при попытке заполнить третий столбец, заполняется только ячейка в первой строке, все остальные выдают ошибку QStandardItem::setChild: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x1ac53b0

гугл говорит про takeItem(), но он не помогает, да и вряд ли должен, ячейка ведь была пустой, удалять из неё нечего.
Если заполнять ячейки вне цикла, по одной, то все работает как положено.
В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все правильно. Вы в `function1` каждый раз создаете объект `QStandardItem`, а потом вставляете. А в `function2` один раз создаете `QStandardItem` перед циклом и вставляете его `self.model.rowCount()` раз. Поэтому вам и выдается сообщение о том, что у вас происходит дублирование.

Comment: То есть во второй функции объекты должны быть уникальными? Или внутри цикла каждый раз создавать объект заново?

Comment: Объекты должны быть уникальными и соответственно вам придется их создавать заново в цикле.